# Какую коллекцию применить?

Tags: java, коллекции

Например, мы имеем следующий класс:

```java
public class Person{

    private String name;
    private int age;


    public User(String name, int age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public User(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }
}
```

И мне необходимо их отсортировать по имени и возрасту.
Например: если будут `(Andrey, 24)` и `(Vlad, 13)` вывести Andrey и 13 соответственно по алфавиту и номеру возрастания. Какую коллекцию мне использовать? При использовании TreeSet выдает ошибку Comporable.

Comment: Нужно написать метод `compareTo`, в котором будет описано, как сравнивать два объекта вашего класса.

Comment: а можно ли без данного метода и вообще без всего того, что связано с Comparator and Comparable?

Comment: Встречный вопрос - а почему нельзя с этим методом?

Comment: я выполняю задания по курсу, там нельзя вносить изменения в класс насколько я понимаю

Comment: А вы знаете, что такое TreeSet? Этой коллекции в любом случае нужна функция сравнения

Comment: Тогда используйте просто ArrayList вместо TreeSet, используйте для сортировки его метод sort, в который передавайте объект-компаратор.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Достаточно засунуть ф-ю с сигнатурой `int compareTo(T t1, T t2)` в конструктор(Пример сортировки по имени и возрасту):

```
TreeSet<User> treeSet = new TreeSet<User>((User a, User b) -> {
        int compareResult = a.getName().compareTo(b.getName());
        return compareResult == 0 ? a.getAge() - b.getAge() : compareResult;
    });
```

Также можно использовать другие коллекции - любые коллекции, реализующие интерфейс List, если вам не нужно, чтобы коллекция всегда была отсортирована(Например, `ArrayList`):

```
List<User> arrayList = new ArrayList();
arrayList.sort((User a, User b) -> {
        int compareResult = a.getName().compareTo(b.getName());
        return compareResult == 0 ? a.getAge() - b.getAge() : compareResult;
    });
```

А если хочется эти два примера, но покороче:

```
TreeSet<User> treeSet = new TreeSet<User>(Comparator.comparing(User::getName).thenComparing(Comparator.comparing(User::getAge)));

arrayList.sort(Comparator.comparing(User::getName).thenComparing(Comparator.comparing(User::getAge)));
```